# Fetching dynamic Id part from URL in Ember JS

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have a route pointing to URL  **"http.appname.com/employee/:empid/addproject"**.

Now how can I get the dynamic part **:empid** in the controller?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the params for a specific route using [`paramsFor()`](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/3.5/classes/Route/methods/paramsFor?anchor=paramsFor) method of a some route. For example `this.paramsFor(this.routeName)` would return params for the route this code is executed in.

Controller has access to it's corresponding route via [`target`](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/3.5/classes/Controller/properties/target?anchor=target) property.

Putting this two pieces together you could access the params from it's controller by doing `this.target.paramsFor(this.target.routeName)`.

Answer (score -1):

Your link to your dynamic segment route should be like:

```
{{link-to (concat "go to addproject with empid=" empid) "addproject" empid }}
```

Your `router` should be like this for enabling dynamic parameters:

```
this.route('addproject', {path: '/employee/:empid/addproject'});
```

In your `addproject model`, you can reach dynamic segment parameter like:

```
model: function(dto){
    return {
        empid: dto.empid
    };
}
```

In your `addproject controller` you can get route model's empid like:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import {alias} from '@ember/object/computed';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

  controllerempid: alias("model.empid")

});
```

Or in your `addpoject template`, you can use dynamic segment defined in your controller like:

```
{{controllerempid}}
```

You can take a look at [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/4ad9d2a777ae9863ca27a3649f6f1b06) for this usage.

Comment: This approach requires the params to be included in model. This is often neither wanted nor possible.